# Linux Script Ftp

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I have to make a script that uploads ONLY [ABC][0-100].txt files ('A' or 'B' or 'C' followed by a number and .txt extension) from the directory current at the URL ftp://host/files/, authenticating with the user admin and password 12345.

I already write some lines but doesn`t working for me:

Script code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="host"
USER="admin"
PASSWORD="12345"

DESTINATION=upload

ALL_FILES="A{0..100}.txt B{0..100}.txt C{0..100}.txt"

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd $DESTINATION
mput $ALL_FILES
bye
EOF
```

can u help me grep only file with specified name

Comment: "*doesn`t working for me*" is not a particularly helpful problem statement - can you share what the *expected* and *actual* behaviors of this code are? What error messages are you seeing? [ask]

Comment: doesn`t working reffers to files that are not uploaded to directory if u read the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash version >= 3.1 I suggest to replace

```
ALL_FILES="A{0..100}.txt B{0..100}.txt C{0..100}.txt"
```

with

```
printf -v ALL_FILES "%s " A{0..100}.txt B{0..100}.txt C{0..100}.txt
```

to allow `bash` to expand the expression.

I can't tell you if there are any other problems in your code. I recommend to write all self-defined variable names in lower case.